# Alter table on cluster

Tags: clickhouse

I have to add ability to store Nullable data into some column of existing tables, but this tables have ReplicatedMergeTree engine. So I got a question if exists command alter table on cluster modify column... ?
And how much it will be cost in time?
Thanks!

Comment: Replicated table propagates such changes automatically to all replicas. If you use sharding you need to apply such alter on each shard, manually or using on_cluster. Also you need to apply matching alter on Distributed and Buffer tables if you have them for this table.

Comment: I would suggest re-creating the column (creating another column and reingesting the data, or simply start writing a new version of the data into a new column). Mutations are not "cheap" in ClickHouse and there are no guarantees you get your data uncorrupted in either way.

Comment: I decided use assumeNotNull function for replacing null values in this columns. It will make partitioning performance much better. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax of the modify query on cluster, it will also update the replicas (but it can take a while).

```
ALTER TABLE example_table ON CLUSTER example_cluster MODIFY COLUMN IF EXISTS `example_column` Nullable(UInt8)
```

For the time required to do the operation, it depends on a lot of parameters (the amount of data, the hardware ...), we can't estimate it without more informations.

Usually when we have such modification and we want to ensure that it won't take too much time and that it is working, we make some benchmarks to estimate the time it would take.

Comment: I decided use assumeNotNull function for replacing null values in this columns. It will make partitioning performance much better. Thanks!